# AngularJS dynamically change ngMask

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, mask

I need to dynamically change a mask.

So I'm making this directive to handle it:

```
link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel) {
    $scope.$watch($attrs.ngModel, function(value) {
        if (value.length > 4) {
            $element.attr('mask', '9999  9999');
        } 
        else {
            $element.attr('mask', '99999999');
        }
    });
}
```

The mask is being applied, I'm checking the DOM, but there's no effect whatsoever.

What I am missing here?

Comment: some solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: Hey, @Matheus Lima. Up to this moment, I've found a solution that actually works for your case, as it works for me. It seems you need to build a directive that changes the dynamic value on Angular, through data-binding, while using the $scope.$watch method. I can post an example as an answer

Answer (score 3):

Can you do that logic in the dom instead of the link? Modyfing the attr probably won't do anything as it's already been parsed and it might not be watching it.

```
ng-model="maskModel" mask="{{ maskModel.length > 4 ? '9999  9999' : '99999999' }}"
```

Comment: That's one way to do it. But my validation is more complicated than length > 4, that was just an exampĺe. And since I'll need that in a lot of places, it's better to put that logic inside a directive.

Comment: did you find a working solution to this? I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't what you are asking but it may help others coming here. A good alternative is to define an optional character. To do that just add an '?' after the character you want to be optional:

`mask="9?9999-9999"`

This is great for inputs like Brazilian phone numbers, which can have both 8 or 9 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use `attrs.$observe(..)` instead of `$scope.$watch (..)`.